Full result of qiskit sampler
In Qiskit, I have a quantum circuit of 20 qubits. Hence the measurement result I am expecting is a dictionary of size 2^20. However, the quasi_dists from SamplerV1 and the get_counts() from SamplerV2 are much shorter. Is it because they omit the 0?
If I do need the full result dictionary, is there any way I can access it? Also, is there any way to have the quasi_dists in SamplerV2?
What is the more efficient way to manipulate the individual results? Please share some tips.

Can you provide your code?

The get_counts() function of qiskit return a python dict so I guess the measurement results that are not measured and have for value 0 are not included to save memory space. So if your number of shot is large enough you can just assume other entries are 0.
